# Azure Ubuntu cli sudo waagent -deprovision gives error

Tags: azure

Azure documentation says that the command "sudo waagent -deprovision" must be given to prepare an Azure Ubuntu vm guest server to become an Azure base vm image (via the Azure vm guest GUI capture command).  However, with the official Ubuntu server 15.10 release cli, I get the following error message:

u373U609@vm-todd-3348:~$ sudo waagent -deprovision
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/waagent", line 31, in 
    import azurelinuxagent.agent as agent
ImportError: No module named azurelinuxagent.agent

What must I install to allow the above Azure waagent command to work?

Answer (score 1):

This missing lib installed only for python3. So to use deprovision script use python3.

```
python3 /usr/sbin/waagent -deprovision
```

Comment: Please explain your solution rather than sharing the command

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.  Here is the user guide to install the agent:
[Azure agent user guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-agent-user-guide/)